# I get wrong output for cos(90)

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a calculator and I need to use cosinus. It works fine if I try cos(0), cos(30), but I get an odd output for cos(90) - 6.12323399573677e-17.
I checked the output for my *radiansToDegrees* and it looks ok.
Sinus works fine, for all the codes.
The numbers are in degrees not radians.
I use the latest xCode.

My code:

```
import Foundation
...
func radiansToDegrees (radians: Double)->Double {
    return radians * 180 / M_PI
}
...
let number = degreesToRadians(Double(digitsLabel.text!)!)
digitsLabel.text = "\(cos(number))"
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: What happens if you do `print(number)`. It's difficult to debug this and you haven't shown what digitsLabel.text is.

Comment: cos(90) is 0, 6.12323399573677e-17 is very very close to 0. Its probably just a double accuracy issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947289/swift-double-conversion-inconsistency-how-to-correctly-compare-doubles

Comment: digitsLabel is an UILabel for inputing a number. Treat the variable number as a Double.

Comment: If you have to deal with input in *degrees* then __sinpi/__cospi offer more accuracy, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575277/1187415 and (for Swift) http://stackoverflow.com/a/28600210/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR: the degrees are a red herring. In playground `cos(M_PI_2)` is 6.123233995736766e-17.

Comment: @Grimxn: Yes, but `print(__cospi(90.0/180.0))` prints `0.0`. The advantage of that (non-standard) functions can be that you *don't* have to multiply with π.